# My code is continuously throwing my catch exception and I don't know why

Tags: c#, json, api, xamarin.forms

I am creating a project that uses an API access key to get stock data information. The user types in the stock symbol, and hits a button that will then load all of the stock information. However, when type in a correct stock symbol and click the button to load the information, it continuously throws my catch exception that I set up and I don't know why. I have never used try catch before so am I doing something wrong?

Here is my method in my `SettingsTab.cs` that try's to get the stock info:

```
async void AddStockButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string symbol = symbolEntry.Text.ToLower();
            //Create a try catch block to make sure the symbol exists and isn't already added in the list
            try
            {
                //Create new data manager and pass in the users chosen symbol
                DataManager dataManager = new DataManager(symbol);
                StockData newStockData = await dataManager.GetStock();
            if (stockList.Contains(newStockData))
            {
                //If stock does not exists or is a duplicate, display error alert
                //Change success label text to Unsuccessful, change color to red, & make visible
                await DisplayAlert("DUPLICATE STOCK", "This stock is already added to your favorites!", "OKAY");
                successLabel.Text = "Unsuccessful due to duplicate";
                successLabel.TextColor = Color.Red;
                successLabel.IsVisible = true;
            }
            else if (!stockList.Contains(newStockData))
            {
                //If stock exists and not duplicate, add that stock to a list of stockData
                //Display success alert
                //Make success label visible
                stockList.Add(newStockData);
                await DisplayAlert("STOCK ADDED", "This stock has been successfully added to your favorites!", "OKAY");
                successLabel.IsVisible = true;

                MessagingCenter.Send<StockData>(newStockData, "NewStockData");
            }

            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("API FAILED","Unable to retrieve data for that symbol. Please check that you typed it correctly or try again later.", "GO BACK");
                successLabel.Text = "Unsuccessful due to API error";
                successLabel.TextColor = Color.Red;
                successLabel.IsVisible = true;
            }
        }
```

and here is my `DataManager.cs` class that gets the API and converts it to json:

```
public class DataManager
    {
        //This class will be responsible for pulling data from remote API
        //And putting it into the stock data opjects and passing it back to normal UI classes
        //Create variables to use
        WebClient apiConnection = new WebClient();
        //Create a string to start API
        string startAPI = "http://api.marketstack.com/v1/eod/latest?accesskey=<<ACCESS KEY REDACTED>>";
        string Symbols { get; set; }
        
        string ApiEndPoint
        {
            get
            {
                return startAPI + Symbols;
            }
        }

        public DataManager(string symbolsToDownload)
        {
            //make symbols equal to whatever gets passed in
            Symbols = symbolsToDownload;
        }

        public async Task<StockData> GetStock()
        {
            //Create a string representation of the downloaded data from ApiEndPoint
            string apiString = await apiConnection.DownloadStringTaskAsync(ApiEndPoint);

            //Create a JObject to store the apiString as a parsed JObject to get access
            //to the json formatted data
            JObject jsonData = JObject.Parse(apiString);

            //create another JObject
            JObject firstStock = (JObject)jsonData["data"][0];

            Debug.WriteLine(firstStock.ToString());

            //Create a new StockData object
            StockData stockData = new StockData();
            stockData.StockName = firstStock["symbol"].ToString();
            //We need to get the string value and parse it as a Double to define the stock Data property
            stockData.OpenPrice = Double.Parse(firstStock["open"].ToString());
            stockData.ClosePrice = Double.Parse(firstStock["close"].ToString());
            stockData.HighPrice = Double.Parse(firstStock["high"].ToString());
            stockData.LowPrice = Double.Parse(firstStock["low"].ToString());
            stockData.Volume = Double.Parse(firstStock["adj_volume"].ToString());
            stockData.Exchange = firstStock["exchange"].ToString();
            stockData.TradingDay = DateTime.Parse(firstStock["open"].ToString());

            //return the new stock data object
            return stockData;
        }
    }
```

Am I just using my try catch the wrong way? Everything I find online, confuses me.. I'm still a student and learning so I apologize if this is a silly question. Please help me

Comment: When you say "continuously" do you mean "continually"? Continuously implies that it's being thrown without your code running. Continually means it throws every time your code runs.

Comment: You get an exception. But what is its Message? Also inspect InnerException. "Something " is wrong and the exception tells you *what*

Comment: What is `ex.ToString()`?

Comment: You shouldn't have posted your access key on SO. Make sure you get a new one.

Comment: Having an exception just to tell your users that something has gone wrong without logging the information received is pretty useless. The Exception object passed to the handler is full of informations about where and why you got the error. Just for now put a breakpoint in the exception handler and tell us what is the _ex.Message_ value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you paste your url into your browser

```
string startAPI = "http://api.marketstack.com/v1/eod/latest?accesskey=<<ACCESS KEY REDACTED>>&symbol=AAPL";
```

you will get back this very friendly and explicit error message

```
{
  "error":
  {
    "code": "missing_access_key",
    "message": "You have not supplied an API Access Key. [Required format: access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY]"
  }
}
```

`accesskey` should be `access_key`

Comment: The access key has been redacted. It's not part of the problem.

Comment: OP is using the wrong name for the `access_key` parameter

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the value of access_key is transmitted correctly and the value is correct.
2. Add a breakpoint in the first line of try to see where the error occurred.
3. Print out "ex" in the catch to view the specific information of the error.